# Convert Type "String" to type "Name"

Tags: lotus-domino

Here is the Problem:

```
    import lotus.domino.Document;
    import lotus.domino.Name;
    import lotus.domino.NotesException;
    import lotus.domino.Session;
    import de.bcode.utils.Utils;


    public class Example {

    int x;

    Name n = (Name)x.toString(); // i want to do this.


    }
```

I am trying to convert above and i also did it by "typecasting" and it has  been failing.

Thank you for reading all the question :-)

Comment: What is `Name`? Your question is very unclear.

Comment: What the errror? and what is the `Name`

Comment: in here you doing integer convert to the string

Comment: Please check - How to create object of 'lotus.domino.Name' in documentation.

Comment: Are trying to create a `Name` from an integer value? The reasons why this gets downvoted to oblivion are
a) your post doesn't explain clearly your objective. 
b) it's not an executable code.
Please try to understand how the basics of Java work and read the relevant API documentation which will usually explain what you need to do to create an object.

Comment: The data Type "Name" is the  Object of class Name(lotus.domino.Name), So i want to convert  or save the String type into Name type which is of domino.name .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API documentation of IBM Notes explains that a Name object can only be obtained from the Session. "To create a new Name object, use createName in Session. " see [this page](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/rnext/help6_designer.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/5b650c0681437c7285256c54004de010?OpenDocument)

```
   Session s = NotesFactory.createSession();
   Name n = s.getUserNameObject();
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will help.Try this

```
   import lotus.domino.Document;
   import lotus.domino.Name;
   import lotus.domino.Session;


   public class Example {

  int x;
  Name n= createName(x.toString());

  }
```